# JS/jQuery multiple categories toggle(+/-) at the same time ,and also an individual toggle for individual category(+/-)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time here with some js/jQuery coding...
I made my categories toogle all at once from one button and also made them toogle individually.

But I do have a problem with the +/- icon which it's like a user interface that says something like your category it's closed or open.
If I access each functionality individually there's no problem but if I mix the use of functionalities for example it will say that a category it's closed(display none) and I have the (- which is fold) instead of (+which is unfold)

Here's my code:

```
//individual toogle of category
$(".inside-cgs_main").on("click", function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass("fa-plus")) {
        $(this).removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
    }

    $(this).closest("div").find('.single-category-content').toggle(1000);
});

//all cats toogle
document.getElementById("toggle-category").addEventListener("click", function () {

    if ($('.single-category > .inside-cgs_main').hasClass("fa-plus")) {
        $('.single-category > .inside-cgs_main').removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
    } else {
        $('.single-category > .inside-cgs_main').removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
    }

    $(".single-category-content").toggle(1000);
    $(this).addClass("my-button-selected");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("my-button-selected");

});
```

Main Cats

Also I have an individual +/- 
and the button that toogles all of them

Can I use a loop or something!

An opinion might be helpful so please ...   :)

Cheers! :D

Comment: Show what you have done so far! Please add a jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok,will do and will be back! :)

Comment: Just pay attention that the `if` statement checks only the first category. If you want to do this to all categories you have to use `each`. Anyway, I recommend to insert the `$(".single-category-content").toggle(1000);` to the `if` and do `slideUp` and `slideDown` so you could be sure that the icon and the content will be coordinated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if ($('.single-category > .inside-cgs_main').hasClass("fa-plus")) {
```

This "if" only check the first element. You should do something like this

```
$('.single-category > .inside-cgs_main').each( fucntion() {
  if ( $( this ).hasClass("fa-plus") ) {
    $( this ).removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
  } else {
    $( this ).removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
  }
});
```

And you'll have another problem now. This change every "+" in a "-" and eveny "-" in a "+"
Is this what you really want? Simply "invert" the "selection"?

Comment: Thank you guys! All I needed was an each as you said also here ...Really appreciate your help ! Success! :D